# How can I reuse a base class function in a derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

Let's say we have these four classes:

- BinaryTree,
- SplayTree (which is a sub-class of BinaryTree),
- BinaryNode and
- SplayNode (which is a sub-class of BinaryNode).

In class BinaryTree I have these 2 functions, and in SplayTree I would like to reuse the first one, because it works in the same way as in SplayTree.

```
//BinaryTree.cpp
bool Find(const T &data) const
{
    Node<T> *found = Find2(data, root); 
    //...
} 
virtual Node<T> * Find2(const T &data, Node<T> *node) const
{
    //...
}

//SplayTree.cpp
using BinaryTree::Find; 
virtual SplayNode<T> * Find2(const T &data, SplayNode<T> *node) const
{
    //...
}
```

Now, the problem is when I have an instance of SplayTree and I call Find, the Binary::Find2 is called instead of SplayTree::Find2, which is what I want.

So, how can I do this?

EDIT:

Corrected some mistakes and refactored the quetion, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: The answer you have accepted is not a solution to your real problem, but rather a different design approach. The actual problem is that `SplayTree::Find2` is not an override of `BinaryTree::Find2` due to the different set of arguments. C++ does not allow for covariant arguments (only covariant return) in overriding functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [CRTP](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Curiously_Recurring_Template_Pattern) idiom is used to solve problems like this. Basically, you derive from a template that gets the derived class as a template parameter, so you can use the type in return values etc.

In your instance, you need to create a common base-template for the two tree-types and implement your `Find` there, while implementing `Find2` in the derived classes:

```
template <class T> class BaseTree
{
public:
  bool Find()
  {
    typename T::NodeType* NodePtr = static_cast<T*>(this)->Find2(...);
  }
}

template <class T>
class BinaryTree<T> : public BaseTree<BinaryTree<T>>
{
public:
  typedef Node<T> NodeType;
  NodeType Find2(); // will be called from BaseTree
};

template <class T>
class SplayTree : public BaseTree<SplayTree<T>>
{
  typedef SplayNode<T> NodeType;
  NodeType Find2(); // dito
};
```

This basically implements 'static polymorphism'. The benefit against normal polymorphism is that you can use return types as you'd like.

**Edit:** Added more detailed description to better suit the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is that `SplayTree::Find2` is not an override of `BinaryTree::Find2`, but rather a different overload (that at the same time hides the original function). The reason why it is a different function is that C++ has support for covariant return types, but not arguments to methods, and thus

At the `BinaryTree` level the call to `Find2` takes an argument of type `Node<T>`, and the only override for such a method is `BinaryTree::Find2`. If you want the method call to be dispatched to the most derived type, you have to override the method, that is provide a method with the same exact signature in the most derived class.