# C++: How to perform the same function in a derived class as in the parent class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, matrix, statistics, linear-algebra

I'm a C++ beginner benefiting very much from this website.

I have a questions that I've been working on for several days and I'm pretty stuck.

To give a simpler version of my problem, I have a perfectly functional class (library downloaded), say, called ProMatrix.  This class performs all kinds of matrix operations such as addition, subtraction, and multiplication.

I also created my version of (derived) matrix class, say, called MyMatrix.  I want MyMatrix class to perform the same kinds of matrix operations as the ProMatrix, but I want them to return things in MyMatrix format.  Is there any short cut to do this???

I looked up on websites, but the examples given there only deal with void output and these functions don't do much inside.

[How can I reuse a base class function in a derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634295/how-can-i-reuse-a-base-class-function-in-a-derived-class)
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Foverload_member_fn_base_derived.htm

Longer version of the story (original problem):  I have downloaded TNT to do matrix operations, but they somehow don't find inverse or transpose... :(
http://wiki.cs.princeton.edu/index.php/TNT  There I saw some kind person wrote the two needed functions.  I struggled but I was able to incorporate them in TNT by modifying the downloaded header files, but it seems kind of dangerous to touch original codes.  I couldn't figure out how to write my own header file to add these functions.  So I figured that maybe I could create my own matrix class derived from TNT's Array2D, with all the properties of the parent class and also with inverse and transpose.

I'm sure there are better, cleaner ways to do it...  Could you please recommend how I approach this problem?  I'm really eager to develop my C++ skills and I would appreciate your time and help very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach is to write free functions for the additional operations; they take arguments of the original class type. So:

```
void transpose(ProMatrix& m); // transpose m in place
```

or

```
ProMatrix transpose(const ProMatrix& m); // return transpose of m
```